# Elegant way to replace multiple values in pandas dataframe without map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, str-replace

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ethnicity': ['AMERICAN INDIAN/ALASKA NATIVE', 'WHITE - BRAZILIAN', 'WHITE-RUSSIAN','HISPANIC/LATINO - COLOMBIAN',
                                 'HISPANIC/LATINO - MEXICAN','ASIAN','ASIAN - INDIAN','ASIAN - KOREAN','PORTUGUESE','MIDDLE-EASTERN','UNKNOWN',
                                 'USER DECLINED','OTHERS']})
```

[image]

I would like to replace the ethnicity column values. For ex : If the value is `ASIAN - INDIAN`, I would like to just replace it as `ASIAN`.

Similarly I would like to do the replace for strings containing `AMERICAN`,`WHITE`,`HISPANIC` and rest others be replaced as `others`. This is what I was trying

```
df1.loc[df.ethnicity.str.contains('WHITE'),'ethnicity'] = "WHITE"
df1.loc[df.ethnicity.str.contains('ASIAN'),'ethnicity'] = "ASIAN"
df1.loc[df.ethnicity.str.contains('HISPANIC'),'ethnicity'] = "HISPANIC"
df1.loc[df.ethnicity.str.contains('AMERICAN'),'ethnicity'] = "AMERICAN"
df1.loc[df.ethnicity.str.contains(other ethnicities),ethnicity] = "Others" # please note here I don't know how to replace all other ethnicities at once as others
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with `.map()`?

Comment: You can always use `np.select` to chain your conditions.

Comment: I may not always know what other ethnicity values might come in my real data which has more than million rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by values of lists and for match is returned `NaN`s, so add [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
L = ['WHITE','ASIAN','HISPANIC','AMERICAN']

print (f'({"|".join(L)})')
(WHITE|ASIAN|HISPANIC|AMERICAN)

df1.ethnicity = df1.ethnicity.str.extract(f'({"|".join(L)})', expand=False).fillna('Others')
```

Or you can join valeus in string:

```
df1.ethnicity = (df1.ethnicity.str.extract('(WHITE|ASIAN|AMERICAN|HISPANIC)', expand=False)
                    .fillna('Others'))
```

---

```
print (df1)
   ethnicity
0   AMERICAN
1      WHITE
2      WHITE
3   HISPANIC
4   HISPANIC
5      ASIAN
6      ASIAN
7      ASIAN
8     Others
9     Others
10    Others
11    Others
12    Others
```

Comment: Wow. just a single line. upvoted. does str extract works like this `str.extract(|'WHITE'|'ASIAN'|'AMERICAN'|HISPANIC')?

Comment: @SSMK - yes, you are close `df1.ethnicity = df1.ethnicity.str.extract('(WHITE|ASIAN|AMERICAN|HISPANIC)', expand=False).fillna('Others')`

Comment: So the `L` is used to extract the string (`ASIAN - INDIAN`) from dataframe and replace it again with `L`(`ASIAN)?

Comment: @SSMK - no, it is only for create `(WHITE|ASIAN|HISPANIC|AMERICAN)` from values from list `L`

Comment: @SSMK - solutions are same, first create `(WHITE|ASIAN|HISPANIC|AMERICAN)` from list and pass to `extract`, second pass `(WHITE|ASIAN|HISPANIC|AMERICAN)` to extract only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203878/discussion-between-ssmk-and-jezrael).